# JavaScript Classes: Member Defined In Constructor Undefined?

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, ecmascript-6

I have a class called UrlBuilder that iterates through a .json file then builds URLs. I can get to the point of looping through the data and printing the correct output, but when I try to push it to an array defined in the classes constructor, I'm told the array is undefined.

Here is my code:

```
"use strict";
const DATA = require("../resources/data.json").services;

class UrlBuilder {

    constructor() {
        this.serviceArr = [];
    }

    static _iterateAndBuild(current_val, index, array) {
        for(let path of current_val.paths) {
            let url = current_val.baseURL + Object.values(path);
            this.serviceArr.push(url);
        }

        let recHistUrl = current_val.server + current_val.recordHistoryUrl;
        serviceArr.push(recHistUrl);

        console.log("Pushing this value to array: " + recHistUrl);
    }

    buildServiceArr() {
        DATA.forEach(UrlBuilder._iterateAndBuild);
    }

}

module.exports = UrlBuilder;
```

As you can see, I broke the callback function out of the forEach. So when I call `UrlBuilder.buildServiceArr`, it loops through the DATA objects and performs the callback written above it.

Here is the output:

> *C:\Users\payton.juneau\Desktop\Me\Projects\Node\com.etouchmenu.serviceSpyGlass>node
>   app.js
>   C:\Users\payton.juneau\Desktop\Me\Projects\Node\com.etouchmenu.serviceSpyGlass\utilities\urlBuilder.js:13
>               this.serviceArr.push(url);
>                    ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'serviceArr' of undefined
>       at _iterateAndBuild (C:\Users\payton.juneau\Desktop\Me\Projects\Node\com.etouchmenu.serviceSpyGlass\utilities\urlBuilder.js:13:18)
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at UrlBuilder.buildServiceArr (C:\Users\payton.juneau\Desktop\Me\Projects\Node\com.etouchmenu.serviceSpyGlass\utilities\urlBuilder.js:23:14)
>       at Object. (C:\Users\payton.juneau\Desktop\Me\Projects\Node\com.etouchmenu.serviceSpyGlass\app.js:10:12)
>       at Module._compile (module.js:660:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:671:10)
>       at Module.load (module.js:573:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (module.js:513:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (module.js:505:3)
>       at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:701:10)*

Thank you for your time in advance! Probably something dumb like scoping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DATA.forEach(UrlBuilder._iterateAndBuild);
```

should be

```
DATA.forEach(UrlBuilder._iterateAndBuild, this);
```

So that the `this` from `buildServiceArr` is passed through as the `this` of `_iterateAndBuild`.

As a general stylistic comment, if you have a function that isn't supposed to be public as a static, just put it after the class, e.g.

```
class UrlBuilder {
    // ...

    buildServiceArr() {
        DATA.forEach(iterateAndBuild);
    }
}

function iterateAndBuild(current_val, index, array) {
    // ...
}
```

though for your case I'm not sure why it is static and not an instance method, e.g.

```
class UrlBuilder {
    // ...
    _iterateAndBuild(current_val, index, array) {
      // ...
    }

    buildServiceArr() {
        DATA.forEach(this._iterateAndBuild, this);
    }
}
```

That would be much more in line with what you're trying to do.

Comment: Or just pass the whole thing as an arrow function to `forEach`, or simply put it in the body of a  `for (const currentVal of DATA) { … }` loop.

Comment: Hello! This fixes my problem. I wasn't entirely sure of what that "context" parameter meant but now it makes perfect sense. Also, thank you for your comments on the convention in which my code is written. This is something I stress about as I am always trying to organize my code in a way that is the accepted standard. I much appreciate your knowledge for my question!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to push into your array by using

```
 this.serviceArr.push(recHistUrl);
```